# Why is GRASS not thinning a terraflow raster properly?

Tags: raster, grass-gis

I want to convert a raster map encoding directional flows (the output of `r.terraflow`) to a vector map. I'm using `r.thin` to process the output. It terminates successfully with 0 pixels removed during the last iteration. Yet when I try to vectorise the result with `r.to.vect` and `feature=line`, I get the following error message:

```
Extracting lines...
ERROR: Raster map is not thinned properly.
   Please run r.thin.
```

I have tried rerunning `r.thin` on the already thinned output, with the same result. I did not find anything in the documentation of either `r.thin` or `r.to.vect` to suggest what might be the problem here or how to fix it.

Answer (score 3):

In case it is relevant:

`r.thin` changed behaviour from GRASS 6 to GRASS 7.  In GRASS 6, cells with non-0 values are considered for thinning, while in GRASS 7, cells with non-null values are considered for thinning.

This means that you may have to change your 0 cells to null cells before r.thin will work as expected.
All cells with non-null values are considered by r.thin in GRASS 7, so if the input raster contains cells with value 0, the result could also contain cells with value 0.

Answer (score 1):

The [r.thin](http://grass.osgeo.org/grass64/manuals/html64_user/r.thin.html) module will thin only the non-zero cells in a raster map. Please check that this condition is fulfilled. Perhaps you have to [r.null](http://grass.osgeo.org/grass64/manuals/html64_user/r.null.html) on the map to set no data pixels to NULL beforehand.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I've tried both adding a null map and removing it with r.null and I get the same result. Any other ideas?

Answer (score 1):

I know this question is history now but in case anybody else comes by looking for help:

I'm not sure why to be honest, but running `r.grow` and `r.reclass` and then `r.thin` seems to work to prepare rasters for `r.to.vect` conversion.

The code should look something like:

```
# reclassify raster, mapping raster values that you want to turn into lines to 1, others to NULL
r.reclass input=my_raster output=my_reclassed_raster rules=reclass_rules.txt 

# grow this reclassified raster a bit (not too much or it will obscure your data)
r.grow input=my_reclassed_raster output=reclassed_grown radius=2

# reclassify this raster by the same rules as before 
# this changes data type of r.grow output back to CELL
r.reclass input=reclassed_grown output=my_grown_reclassed_raster rules=reclass_rules.txt 

# finally we can now run r.thin
r.thin input=my_grown_reclassed_raster output=thinned type=line
```

After all that, `r.to.vect` should work properly on `thinned`